# How to restart swiper slider on clicking button using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, slider, reset, swiper.js, restart

I created an auto sliding carousel using swiper js. Now I want to restart the carousel from beginning by clicking a button. How can I do it? Please help.

```
var swiper2 = new Swiper(".lawnsArtificialTurfSlider", {
    initialSlide: 0,
    spaceBetween: 10,
    autoplay: {
          delay: 4000,
          disableOnInteraction: false,
        },
    navigation: {
      nextEl: ".hero-slider-next",
      prevEl: ".hero-slider-prev",
    }
  });
```

`<button onclick="resetSlider()">Reset</button>`

`const resetSlider = () => { swiper2.reset(); }`

Answer (score 0):

On click slide to `slide 0` (start) by [slideTo](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#method-swiper-slideTo) method.

```js
/* swiper.slideTo(index, speed, runCallbacks) */
swiper.slideTo(0);
```

Speed 0 (Moves without animation):

```js
/* swiper.slideTo(index, speed, runCallbacks) */
swiper.slideTo(0,0);
```

**Snippet:**

```js
var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
  spaceBetween: 30,
  centeredSlides: true,
  autoplay: {
    delay: 2500,
    disableOnInteraction: false,
  },
  pagination: {
    el: ".swiper-pagination",
    clickable: true,
  },
  navigation: {
    nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
    prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
  },
});

/* click event */
document.getElementById("restart").addEventListener("click", restart);

function restart() {
  swiper.slideTo(0);
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

#restart{
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

body {
  background: #eee;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.swiper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.swiper-slide {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #fff;
  /* Center slide text vertically */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.swiper-slide img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<!-- Link Swiper's CSS -->
<link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css"
      />

<button id="restart">Restart</button>
<!-- Swiper -->
<div class="swiper mySwiper">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
  <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
</div>

<!-- Swiper JS -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>


<!-- Initialize Swiper -->
<script>
  
</script>
```